# Windows Azure VM Share Folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, network-share, azure

This must be pretty simple but I can't figure it out !! :)

I have two Windows Azure VM's - all I want to do is have a network share on one that is accessible from the other.

Do I need to set up some kind of network or firewall rules or something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a virtual network. The Azure VMs you have at the moment are discrete VMs unaware of each others existence. When you create a Virtual Network and add your machines to it, they become part of the same subnet and can discover and address each other. This should help you http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/add-a-vm-to-a-virtual-network/

Answer (score 0):

Azure VMs can connect to each-other out of the box if they are *in the same Cloud Service*. Then, you can enable network file sharing and share files between them normally.

Please [see here for instructions](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/connect-to-a-cloud-service/) on how to create VMs in the same Cloud Service.

If the above is correctly set up, you can access one VM from another via its hostname. So if you have a VM called "vm123" and a folder "shareXYZ" which that VM is sharing on the network, other VMs in the same Cloud Service will be able to access it at "\vm123\shareXYZ", as you would expect.

Cheers!

--

Vlad